# Por que Elmah.Mvc solicita autenticação quando requiresAuthentication=false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de saber por que o `Elmah.Mvc` quando entramos na página `~/Elmah` ele sempre solicita login da minha aplicação?
  A opçao no `webconfig requiresAuthentication` está como `false` e mesmo assim solicita.
    Alguém já passou por isso?